# Select unique combinations of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table called TEST with two columns F1 and F2, which are both integers. 
Say TEST looks like this:

```
F1|F2
-----
 1|2
 2|1
 1|3
 4|1
```

Essentially, I want to return results that look like this:

```
F1|F2
-----
 1|2
 1|3
 4|1
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a select statement that will ignore row (b,a) if (a,b) already exists and still select all rows where its reverse does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` check to see if there is an entry in the table which has the same values but in a different order. We also add the condition that the `F2` value is greater than the `F1` value so that we don't exclude both `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`, and we use `DISTINCT` so we don't get multiple entries where `F1` = `F2` (e.g. `(2,2)`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1, F2
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT F1, F2 
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.F1 = t1.F2 AND t2.F2 = t1.F1 AND t2.F2 > t2.F1)
ORDER BY F1, F2
```

Output:

```
F1  F2
1   2
1   3
4   1
```

[Demo on SQLFIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b313/1)

Comment: The `select distinct` is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I put it in for the possibility that there are two rows of e.g. `(2,2)` and `(2,2)`. The demo has that in there. Although OP didn't say that could happen they didn't say it couldn't either.